# How to create a scrollable panel of components in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, panel, scrollpane

So, basically, I'm trying to achieve this a scrollable set of components with spacing etc. and the ability to add more components.
The list of components are custom anchorpane components.

Here's an example that I got working:
[image]

The problem is that that uses a gridpane inside of a scrollpane and for some reason the gridpane does not fill the width of the scrollpane at all. So, if I resize, everything stays where it is instead of stretching inside the gridpane columns. Also, if I were to stick to a gridpane (over a tilepane which seems to work better except when the components float next to each other despite the orientation being vertical and prefcolumns being 1), how would I add more rows? The idea of this is to list github repos in  a nice, UX pleasing, fashion.

Thanks for any insight.
Also: those repos aren't mine - I have none and a guy on a website made that (it's not well made so don't compare me to him lol).

Comment: How about [Enrich your List UI by using the MediaListCell](http://www.guigarage.com/2014/09/enrich-list-ui-using-medialistcell/). Otherwise provide some code.

Comment: @Roland - Currently I'm prototyping everything in scene builder but I think I may have to start making the custom components w/ code soon to get the functionality that I would like. That link is interesting though, I'll use that for another part of the program. Right now, I'm just looking for a purely FXML based solution.

Comment: Looks like you could do that simply with a `VBox` in a `ScrollPane`. `fillWidth="true"` for the `VBox` and `fitToWidth="true"` for the `ScrollPane`. If you want a `GridPane` use the `columnConstraints` to control the width. But, create a simple example and post some code if you want a more complete answer.

Comment: @James_D Your idea works great. Is there anyway for it to be possible to make the components in the VBox (anchorpanes) stretch to fit the width of the VBox?

Comment: Setting `fitToWidth` to `true` on the scroll pane should be enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like you should use a `VBox` to hold your `AnchorPane`s and put them in a `ScrollPane`. Set `fitToWidth` to `true` on the `ScrollPane` and it should force the anchor panes to take up the whole width (and no more) of the scroll pane's viewport, assuming you don't change the `maxWidth` property on the `AnchorPane` from its default.

Mocked-up example (which can easily be done in FXML if you prefer):

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollingVBox extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final Random rng = new Random();
        VBox content = new VBox(5);
        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(content);
        scroller.setFitToWidth(true);

        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
            String style = String.format("-fx-background: rgb(%d, %d, %d);"+
                    "-fx-background-color: -fx-background;",
                    rng.nextInt(256),
                    rng.nextInt(256),
                    rng.nextInt(256));
            anchorPane.setStyle(style);
            Label label = new Label("Pane "+(content.getChildren().size()+1));
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(label, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(label, 5.0);
            Button button = new Button("Remove");
            button.setOnAction(evt -> content.getChildren().remove(anchorPane));
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(button, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(button, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(button, 5.0);
            anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(label, button);
            content.getChildren().add(anchorPane);
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(scroller, null, null, addButton, null), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Another solution might be to use a `ListView`. (This would be preferable if you had many items to display.) Create a class representing the items you are displaying in each `AnchorPane` and a custom list cell to display them.